# Using EmailJS in TypeScript for a contact form, Argument of type 'EventTarget' is not assignable to parameter of type... .ts(2345)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to submit the form below using EmailJS in TypeScript. In the line `.sendForm("gmail", "websiteID",  e.target, "user_ID")` this is giving me an error `e.target`.

**Argument of type 'EventTarget' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | HTMLFormElement'. Type 'EventTarget' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLFormElement': acceptCharset, action, autocomplete, elements, and 247 more.ts(2345)**

I am not sure what to do. Have tried many different things and it doesn't work. Can someone help me understand the issue. Thanks!

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid, Typography, Button, Snackbar } from "@material-ui/core";
import useStyles from "./useStyles";
import MuiAlert, { AlertProps } from "@material-ui/lab/Alert";
import emailjs from "emailjs-com";

function Alert(props: AlertProps) {
  return <MuiAlert elevation={6} variant="filled" {...props} />;
}

export default function Contact() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);


  function sendEmail(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs
      .sendForm("gmail", "websiteID",  e.target, "user_ID")
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
        }
      );
      e.target.reset()
  }

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = (event?: React.SyntheticEvent, reason?: string) => {
    if (reason === "clickaway") {
      return;
    }

    setOpen(false);
  };
  return (
    <Grid id="contact" container className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container className={classes.aboutSection}>
        <Typography className={classes.whiteText}>
          .load(<span className={classes.purpleText}>contact</span>)
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container className={classes.contactBox}>
        <Grid item xs={11}>
          <Grid className={classes.contactboxTitle}>Get in Touch</Grid>
          <form className={classes.inputBox} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
            <Grid container item xs={6}>
              <Grid className={classes.nameTitle}>Full name</Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid className={classes.topcontactBox}>
              <textarea className={classes.nameInput} name='name'/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container item xs={6}>
              <Grid className={classes.nameTitle}>Email</Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid className={classes.middlecontactBox}>
              <textarea className={classes.emailInput} name='email'/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container item xs={6}>
              <Grid className={classes.nameTitle}>Message</Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid className={classes.buttomcontactBox}>
              <textarea
                placeholder="Add your message here"
                className={classes.messageInput}
                name='message'
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid>
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                className={classes.sendButton}
                onClick={handleClick}>
                Send
              </Button>
              <Snackbar
                open={open}
                autoHideDuration={3000}
                onClose={handleClose}>
                <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="success">
                  Message successfully sent
                </Alert>
              </Snackbar>
            </Grid>
          </form>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, the `.target` of an event is the innermost element that the event was dispatched to. For example, you might have a `<button>` inside a `<div>`. If the `<div>` has a click listener, and you click the button, the button will be the `event.target`. (Look up event bubbling and capturing.)

So, even if you know the element the listener is attached to, `event.target` is not safe in general, because any of the descendants of the element may be the target instead. Rather, you should use `.currentTarget`, which refers to the element the listener is attached to, instead of the (innermost) element the event was dispatched to.

```
.sendForm("gmail", "websiteID",  e.currentTarget, "user_ID")
```

and you'll also need to change

```
e.target.reset()
```

to

```
e.currentTarget.reset()
```

but given that this is React, rather than using `.reset`, instead, I would highly recommend using controlled components and setting their state explicitly - that'll be a much more reliable method.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't submit my form either